# Property 'loading$' does not exist on type 'MatTableDataSource'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to build angular  app to prod. I used for data grid as `MatTableData`.

I am getting an error when try to build to prod with `ng build --prod`inlike below:

```
Property 'loading$' does not exist on type 'MatTableDataSource'
```

Here is how I implement in a component:

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee>();

ngOnInit(){

this.repository.getData(`employee/list`).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.dataSource.data = res as Employee[];
  }
)

}
```

It throws this error in the template:

```
<div class="mat-table__bottom">
    <!-- MATERIAL SPINNER | Url: 'https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/overview' -->
    <mat-spinner [diameter]="20" *ngIf="dataSource.loading$ | async"></mat-spinner>
    <!-- MATERIAL PAGINATOR | Binded to dasources -->
    <!-- See off.documentations 'https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview' -->
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]" [length]="dataSource.paginatorTotal$ | async"
        [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

So how can ı fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: The error message is pretty straightforward - the MatTableDataSource does no contain such property - see the [source](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts). It works during `ng serve` as it's not as strict in it's validators as it is during proper build.

Perhaps your `loading$` is an observable directly on your component?

Anyway, if you need further help please reproduce your issue on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatTableDataSource` doesn't have `loading$` property. To fix it you need to declare and handle `loading$` subject in your component:

```
public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Employee>();
public loading$ = new Subject<boolean>();
```

Then emit values while loading data:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.loading$.next(true);
  this.repository.getData(`employee/list`)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.loading$.next(false)))
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dataSource.data = res as Employee[];
      }
    )
}
```

And finally in template change `dataSource.loading$` to `loading$`

Additional information:

When using `ng build --prod` there are perfomed additional type checks and you get error, while in normal `ng serve` your `loading$` is always treated as `undefined`